# In MS Access 2010, How do you get rid of the 'Add New' tab in the navigation control?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to remove the space the [Add New] tab is taking up in the navigation control.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Add New] links disappear when you switch to **Form View** from Design View.  So your users should never see it, unless you are allowing users to modify the application.

This effect is illustrated in [this video](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/en-us/office/media/video/office.html?cid=office-video&VideoID=98ce156b-93bd-45ac-b399-57093fc988cc&from=mscomoffice), at 5:00 minutes into the talk.

Comment: Right, but the space it takes up is visible in form view.  I should've been more clear that that's what I was referring to.  Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: I doubt it.  Sounds like they're just making the link invisible under the hood.  If the fonts for the tabs are controllable, you could try making them a little smaller.  That should free up enough room for an additional tab, if that's what you're after.